# How to nofollow images on front page of wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, images

My new theme has killed my page authority and global rank. Part of the issue is that my theme is creating two links per post on the front page. One link to the article from the title, and one link to the article from the image at the same time.

The Newspaper 11 theme I am using seems to be very un SEO friendly.

How can I nofollow the thumbnails on the front page of my site?

Answer (score 2):

Two links to the same destination on the same page is unlikely to be the cause of your problems. When Googlebot sees a second link to another page, it completely ignores it:

- It doesn't pass extra Pagerank to it
- It doesn't associate the anchor text of the second link with the page

From my testing, Google treats the second link pretty much as if it didn't exist.

The one exception is if the second link has a different fragment identifier.  For some reason, Google treats these two URLs as *different* when they are both linked in the same page even though they necessarily both link to the same document:

- `https://example.com/page.html`
- `https://example.com/page.html#fragment`

---

You don't want to use `nofollow` in this situation. In general, `nofollow` should never be used on internal links (links within your site to your own site.) More specifically in the case of duplicate links, when you `nofollow` one of two links to a destination, Google treats **both** links as if they were nofollowed.  Their logic is that if the link is marked as untrusted in one place, Google should treat all instances of it as such.

Your new theme may be causing SEO problems somehow, but the mechanism you propose has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Well that explanation does make me feel so much better.